# A curious trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a simple proof of the following conjectured identity?
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n+1}- \cos\frac{j\pi}{n}\right)=2\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n+1}- \cos\frac{j\pi}{n+1}\right).$$

Comment: second equation typo

Comment: OK, at least that conjecture jumps over the first hurdle: numerically correct for  $1\le n\le1000$ :)

Comment: What led to this, if you please?

Comment: I am also curious how it appeared.

Comment: @Allawonder: Let $G_n=\left(g(i,j)\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ with $g(0,0)=1$ and $g(i,j)=1$ for $|i-j|=1$ and $g(i,j)=0$ else. The computation of the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $2 \cos\frac{\pi}{2n+1}$ led to the above identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a consequence of [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038523/215011)
$$
2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\cos\theta - \cos\frac{k\pi}n\right)=\frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta}.
$$